# Has wp_get_attachment_image_src changed from 3.2.1 to 3.5.2?

Tags: images

I just upgraded my app from 3.2.1 to 3.5.2 and now I'm having an issue where my image `src`s are blank in one of my pages. The databases are identical (since I just did a mysql dump/restore a few minutes ago). Here's my code:

category-legends.php:

```
if(file_exists($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.substr($fivesdraft->guid_legend,20)))
    {               
       $featured = gangmei_get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $fivesdraft->ID );
       echo '<li class="legends-thumb"><div class="img-wrapper"><a href="/?legends='.$fivesdraft->post_name.'"><img src="'.$featured.'" alt="'.$fivesdraft->name.'" /></div><p><a href="/?legends='.$fivesdraft->post_name.'">'.$fivesdraft->name.'</a></p></li>';
    }
```

functions.php:

```
    function gangmei_get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id = NULL) {
        global $id;
        $post_id = (NULL === $post_id) ? $id : $post_id;
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id), 'full');
        $src = $src[0];
        return $src;
    }
```

get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id) is returning an ID, so I'm thinking that maybe there's something wrong with `wp_get_attachment_image_src`. Can anyone lead me in the right direction? How would I debug this? The old version works fine (all images have a `src` and show properly) but my other environment doesn't. It's producing images like this: `<img alt="Nick Aries" src="">`

=====

var_dump( $src );

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: Try saving your Permalink structure.  If you dumped the DB from one server and imported to another, you might have permalink issues.  Saving your Permalink structure might help.

Comment: How would I save my permalink structure? (sorry I'm a complete WP beginner). The only thing I know to do is after dumping the db I have to go to wp-admin, settings, permalink, and save (which I did). Are there other steps?

Comment: No, that's the step I meant.  OK, so that's not it.  Is the `alt` text correct?

Comment: Yep alt is correct, just no `src`

Comment: It's supposed to look like this: `src="http://www.mysite.com/images/mysite/pioneers/legends/Nick-Aries.jpg"`

Comment: In the `gangmei_get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` function, right after the `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` line, add `var_dump( $src );`, and add the result of that to your question.  Might help narrow down the issue.

Comment: I updated it. It prints bool(false)?

Comment: Make sure that the post in question has a Featured Image set.  If it doesn't, then your function will return `false`.

Comment: The core function hasn't changed since 3.1, so it's something to do with your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try this first

Make sure that the post in question has its Featured Image (formerly Post Thumbnail) set.

## Then...

Going by our comment thread, here's something else to try.

```
function gangmei_get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id = NULL) {
    /*
     * global $id;
     * $post_id = (NULL === $post_id) ? $id : $post_id;
     * $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id), 'full');
     * $src = $src[0];
     */
    global $post;
    if( NULL === $post_id ) {
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ) );
    if( !is_array( $src ) && ! $src ) {
        return false; // there's an error somewhere
    }
    return $src[0];
}
```

Comment: Didn't work... same as before

Comment: what's a featured image set?

Comment: See https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Setting_a_Post_Thumbnail for information on setting a post's or page's Featured Image.

Comment: Ok so I looked at the edit page of one of my posts and it doesn't have a Featured Image, but the old version of my blog does and has a thumbnail of it. Why is that? I just did a dump/restore of the database shouldn't they be identical?

Comment: OK, if there's no Featured Image, that's the source of your problem. Your original code is probably fine.  As for the dump/restore issue, I can't really speak to that.  Usually when I'm moving a site, I use the WordPress **Tools >> Export** and **Tools >> Import** menus.

Comment: So is there a systematic way of solving this through WP-admin? Or do I have to upload them one by one?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know.  You might want to start a new question about reattaching featured images after a DB export/import.