# Featured images disappear after DB export/import?

Tags: images

I'm upgrading my blog right now from 3.2.1 to 3.5.2. However, for one section the featured images have seem to disappeared. The database is identical since I just did a dump/restore a few minutes ago.

Other sections are fine, but for this one I am no longer receiving an array when I do `wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id), 'full');` even though all the parameters are correct. I checked my edit post page on wp-admin and there is no longer an image under `Featured Images` as there was before.

Is there a way to recover these images without having to upload them one by one? I'm pretty sure it's not a permalink issue, since I did the settings > permalink > save thing already.

Comment: Identical, as in _really_ identical? No modifications at all between export and import?

Comment: And does this "section" has anything special about it?

Comment: Nope. None except the mandatory WP database upgrade. There shouldn't be anything special about it (not that I know of). Here's the code that's screwing me up: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105089/has-wp-get-attachment-image-src-changed-from-3-2-1-to-3-5-2

Comment: But how both Questions relate? Ain't that one solved?

Comment: No that was just how I came to the conclusion that `Featured images` was not imported